# I am not able to display the details of products in my site

Tags: javascript, php, css

When I click on a product, I want the image to enlarge and also show the details of the product. Enlarging of image is working but I cannot get the details of the product.

Here is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function($){
        var addToAll = false;
        var gallery = true;
        var titlePosition = 'inside';
        $(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var title = $this.attr('title');
            var src = $this.attr('data-big') || $this.attr('src');
            var a = $('<a href="#" class="fancybox"></a>').attr('href', src).attr('title', title);
            $this.wrap(a);
        });
        if (gallery)
            $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'fancyboxgallery');
        $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
            titlePosition: titlePosition
        });
    });
    $.noConflict();
</script>
```

fancy box

```
<div class="fancybox" align="center">
<?php
require_once("admin/config/connection.php");
$proname   = "";
$proitems  = "";
$pid       = "";
$query1    = "select * from products where protype='Bicycle/ Tricycle'";
$resource1 = mysql_query($query1, $connection);
$result1   = "";
$id        = "";
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($resource1)) {
    $pid     = $record['pid'];
    $img     = "uploads/" . $record['proimg'];
    $proname = $record['proname'];
    //$proitems=$record['proitem'];
    $result1 .= "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mrgn_less prd'>
              <img class='fancybox' src='$img' >

      </div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: you are not showing the $proname in code.

Comment: could you please tell me where i should show. i want the details to be shown only on clicking the image

Answer (score 0):

You didn't echo the result u have to do it after the while loop. put this after the while loop.

`echo $result1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="fancybox" align="center">
<?php
require_once("admin/config/connection.php");
$proname   = "";
$proitems  = "";
$pid       = "";
$query1    = "select * from products where protype='Bicycle/ Tricycle'";
$resource1 = mysql_query($query1, $connection);
$result1   = "";
$id        = "";
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($resource1)) {
    $pid     = $record['pid'];
    $img     = "uploads/" . $record['proimg'];
    $proname = $record['proname'];
    //$proitems=$record['proitem']; ?>

    <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mrgn_less prd'>
             <div style="float:left;"> <img class='fancybox' src= <?php echo $img; ?> /> </div>
             <div style="float:left;"> <label> Product Name:-</label> <?php echo $proname;?> </div>
<?php } ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: thank u. but this code shows the products along with its details on the first page. i need the details of each product to be shown only when i click on it